# Showing a group does not have a faithful finite-dimensional representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, representation-theory

I am having some difficulty with this problem. We are asked to show that there does not exist any monomorphism to GL(n, $\mathbb{C}$). The group in the domain is defined as follows:

Let G = $(P(\mathbb{R}), \delta)$ where $\delta$ is the symmetric difference operator, and $P(\mathbb{R})$ is the power set of the reals.

I noted that, for all $A \subseteq P(\mathbb{R})$, we have the following:

A$\delta$A = $\emptyset$

A$\delta \emptyset$ = A

A$\delta\mathbb{R}$ = A$^C$

I am not really sure how to use these facts, but the strategy I initially considered was proof by contradiction. I can't seem to find any way to show that any properties of homomorphisms or injectivity are violated, though.

I briefly thought of using a cardinality argument, but I am not sure how to proceed with that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even just a hint would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with cardinality of the reals, is it enough to say that $|P(\mathbb{R})| = 2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ and $|GL(n, \mathbb{C})| \leqslant |\mathbb{C}|^{n^2}$, and then that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^x - x^k$ = 1? Or is that not enough?

Comment: The limit argument seems a bit strange to me as there is no $n$ in the expression and even if there was (the obvious correction $2^x - x^{n^2}$ does not converge to $1$)  I dont see how you would get the desired conclusion. I think you can just note that $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{C}$ and thus as $\mathbb{R}$. However, there is no injective map $P(S) \to S$ for any set $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ has cardinality $\beth_2=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ while $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ has cardinality $\beth_1=2^{\aleph_0}$, so there aren't even any injective *functions* from $G$ to $GL(n,\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen the symbol ℶ before, what does it represent?

Comment: I am referring to [*beth* (i.e. the Hebrew letter $\beth$) numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). Namely, the sequence of cardinals defined recursively as $\beth_0=\aleph_0$, $\beth_{\alpha+1}=\left\lvert2^{\beth_\alpha}\right\rvert$ and, when $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, $\beth_\beta=\sup\limits_{\alpha<\beta}\beth_\alpha$.